# Is it possible to make bones ossify much slower in adults?

Tags: human-biology, bone-biology

According to [Can we artificially increase human growth using HGH](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28515/can-we-artificially-increase-human-growth-using-hgh),

> But during normal human development bones ossify in the process, and in human adults the bones are completely ossified and can't grow in length anymore.

Is it possible to make the ossification process much longer?

Comment: Your question title and body don't match. I think you might be misunderstanding the statement. It isn't saying that bone can't ossify in adults and therefore it can't grow, it is saying that because they have *already* ossified they can't grow. Ossification is basically hardening; completely ossified bone is completely hard and has nowhere to grow from. Ossification can still happen in healing bones in adults after a break, however.

Comment: I do understand, but just missed the "not" in the question. Thank you!

Comment: Ah yes, that changes the meaning entirely, much better now!

Comment: I think what you are asking about is delaying the closure of cartilage growth plates, so that bones continue to grow longitudinally for longer.